# Getting handle to Java Window using abbot class?

Tags: window, abbot

I have a Java window named "swingMainThreadApp". I am trying to get a handle to this window using the abbot class. Could somebody help me regarding this?

Comment: This is to broad. Please clarify, what your exact problem is and what you have tried.

Comment: I just started with the abbot class. We have to use this Java based API for UI Testing. 

While going through the documentation http://abbot.sourceforge.net/doc/overview.shtml

I came across these classes http://abbot.sourceforge.net/doc/api/abbot/tester/WindowTester.html

I want to know how use this abbot API to get handle to a JAVA window (extended from JFrame) if I have the name of the window.

I apologize if my question seems juvenile. I am just a beginner in Java.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I found it. Apparently In Abbot, the window is also treated like a component. I am posting the answer here. It can help other people who have similar doubts.

```
    import abbot.finder.BasicFinder;
    import abbot.finder.Matcher;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import java.awt.Component;

     try
     frame = (JFrame)BasicFinder.getDefault().find(new Matcher()
        {
            public boolean matches(Component c)
            {
                return c instanceof JFrame && c.isShowing() && 
                c.getName().equals(frameName);
            }
        });
    }
    catch(Exception exception){/* do nothing */}
    return frame;
```